# appending query string while rendering a twig template

Tags: templates, twig, query-string

I'm currently working on a simple application using Twig as a template engine. My problem is that I cannot append a query string like `?id=15` while rendering a template (which I can do on a simple redirect) like this:

```
if($booking){
        // render template
        View::renderTemplate('admin/bookings/check_booking.html', ['booking' => $booking]);
    } else {
        self::redirect('/admin/bookings/book-room?id='. $booking->room_id);
    }
```

I don't use any framework like Symfony or others. Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to access the query string inside the template or create a link with one? Just append the querystring, `<a href=admin/bookings/book-room?id={{ booking.getId() }}">Book</a>`

Comment: @DarkBee, It is not what I'm trying to do. I can append a query string to an <a> tag like your wrote. What I want to do is to append somehow a query string while rendering template from my controller as I specified above in this line `View::renderTemplate('admin/bookings/check_booking.html', ['booking' => $booking]);`

Comment: `Twig` can't add anything to a query string though